# Enable Netflix Zuul to redirect traffic to container at another host

Tags: java, docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I've setup Zuul as a docker container with two different applications (let's call Docker application A and Docker application B), on HOST 1.

I've also setup Eureka as a docker container with one application (let's call Docker application C), on HOST 2.

What works: Eureka is able to successfully register application A, B, C and Zuul gateway. Since, Zuul and application A and B are on the same host, both applications (A and B) works great and Zuul integrates correctly with them.

Problem: When I ask Zuul gateway to hit rest endpoint on Application C (which is contained on HOST 2 - the same HOST as Eureka), Zuul is unable to forward the request to HOST 2.

My understanding: So I've clearly seen that, if I launch Application C on the same host as Zuul, it integrates happily and finds the forwarding ipAdd and port. But when I try to launch Application C on HOST 2, Zuul is looking for the ipAdd:Port on the HOST1 (where as the applicaiton is clearly at HOST2) and hence getting into a

> "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error"

F1, please help. Thanks in advance.

I'm attaching the fail trace here:

> WARN 1 --- [nio-8762-exec-1] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
>   com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]

This error comes due to:

> Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: ApplicationC

This trace comes due to:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.17.0.17:8099 [/172.17.0.17] failed: connect timed out
>   Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.17.0.17:8099 [/172.17.0.17] failed: connect timed out
>   [io-8762-exec-10] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when processing request to {}->http://172.17.0.17:8099: No route to host
>   2019-02-10 10:19:08.367  INFO 1 --- [io-8762-exec-10] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://172.17.0.17:8099

Clearly, Zuul is trying to forward the request on HOST1 and hence gets Forwarding error. Application C is on HOST2. How can I tell ZUUL to forward it on HOST2, please. Thanks!

**UPDATE 2**: I ran docker inspect container_ID | grep "IPAddress" -the Ip address of all containers(s) (for all applications and ZUUL) is same as IP address registered in Eureka dashboard. Also, if this helps, I am setting preferIpAddress to true.

> eureka.instance.preferIpAddress: false

Eureka dashboard shows me :

> UPLOADLOCAL(c93c01ff3872:uploadLocal:8099)
>    where UPLOADLOCAL is the serviceId, c93c01ff3872 is the docker containerID, uploadLocal application name and 8099 is the port.

This is my application.yml file for Eureka:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost 
client:
    registerWithEureka: false
fetchRegistry: false 
serviceUrl:
  defaultZone: http://localhost:8877/eureka/
```

Comment: When you ask zuul providing a key to look for, it must be trying to resolve using eureka, and if eureka finds match it returns url it needs forward the request to. So suspect its eureka configurations. Can you confirm from eureka dashboard that the application c which you are trying to hit is registered with HOST2 ipadd?

Comment: your comment was helpful to debug. it's working now. thanks @ravinikam